# C++ Class Library

Tags: class, c++-cli

I opened my win32 console application and added a class library. I am currently trying to use this class library but when I setup the class library with namespace name I can't seem to use String Data Type. It says no default Constructor exists for class "System::String". I can't figure out how to get rid of this error.

Header File

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;

namespace [Name]{

public ref class [Name]
{
private:
    System::String ipaddress;
    System::String port;

public:
    [Constructor](System::String,System::String,System::String);
};
}
```

CPP File

// This is the main DLL file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "header file"

namespace [Name] {

[Name]::[Constructor](System::String ip,System::String portN,System::String protocol)
{
    ipaddress = ip;
    port = portN;

}
}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be a C++ or C++/CLI project? A true "Win32 Console project" is *not* C++/CLI and so you cannot use BCL types, such as `System.String` in those projects.

Comment: Also, are the `[` and `]` characters in your code or are you just obfuscating your names?

Comment: I don't know if Visual C++ have some special features but normally you have to include the corresponding header files to make classes available. I don't see any included header before you are using System::String. If the classes are defined in stdafx.h, I would recommend to include this header in your header file, too.

Comment: Your code is C++/CLI not Standard C++. I have updated the tags assigned to your post but in the future please tag your posts appropriately.

Comment: i was trying to following this tutorial on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the wrong project type.

Create a **Win32 Project** (or *Empty Project*).

You have created a *Class Library*, which is under the CLR category in the *New Project* dialog. This means you don't get a C++ project, but a C++/CLI project.

C++/CLI is a different best. For the record, your code would have to look like this:

```
namespace NamespaceName
{

    public ref class ClassName
    {
    private:
        System::String^ ipaddress;
        System::String^ port;

    public:
        ClassName(System::String^ ip, System::String^ port, System::String^ protocol);
    };

}
```

These `^` characters mean the type is a *managed handle*.
Think of them as if they were `*`, but pointing to a managed object.

But given the tutorial you were trying to follow, this is **not** what you want. So create a plain C++ project and use `std::string` instead of `System::String`, which is a managed type.